# Is the check for 0 value in Report Builder equal to check for NULL value in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, reportbuilder, rdl

In .rdl file of the Report Builder there is such definition for the field:

```
=iif(Fields!F_Subscr.Value <> 0,Fields!Pkz.Value,"")
```

All these fields are coming in a rdl dataset from the some asigned sql query. I need to move all such checks from rdl-level at the level of the underlying sql query.
Is the check Fields!F_Subscr.Value <> 0 equal to the check:

```
CASE WHEN F_Subscr IS NOT NULL THEN pkz ELSE '' END
```

at the sql level?

Comment: Why do you think `<> 0` would be the same as `IS NOT NULL`? How do you imagine the case that `F_Subscr.Value` **is** zero will be treated in the two cases?

Comment: The equivalent of `IS NULL` in SSRS expression is `IsNothing`. Wrapping that in a `Not` would be the equivilent of `IS NOT NULL`. `0` and `NULL` have never been the same value, so you cannot expet `<> 0` and `IS NOT NULL` to ever produce the same results.

Comment: I don't know. That is why I'm asking. So how to get rid of such definition of the field at the level of .rdl and perfom this calculation at the sql-level?

Comment: It seems that the correct way to replace that rdl instruction is to use such sql expression CASE WHEN F_Subscr <> 0 THEN pkz ELSE '' END